# Corda Enterprise RPCClient - Cannot find serialization

Tags: corda

I added SpringBoot for the YO project and works just fine in the open source. When I switch the node to Corda Enterprise I get the following.

Any sugestions?

```
[m[31mW 14:52:27 30 SerializationFactoryImpl.apply - Cannot find serialization scheme for: ([636F726461010000], RPCClient), registeredSchemes are: [net.corda.client.rpc.internal.KryoClientSerializationScheme@4230b013, net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.amqp.AMQPClientSerializationScheme@460f2c8d]
[m[1;31mE 14:52:27 30 client.run - AMQ214000: Failed to call onMessage
[m java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Serialization scheme not supported.
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.NotSupportedSerializationScheme.doThrow(SerializationScheme.kt:19) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.NotSupportedSerializationScheme.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:23) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.withCurrentContext(SerializationAPI.kt:66) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl$deserialize$1.invoke(SerializationScheme.kt:86) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.core.serialization.SerializationFactory.asCurrent(SerializationAPI.kt:80) ~[corda-core-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.serialization.SerializationFactoryImpl.deserialize(SerializationScheme.kt:111) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.nodeapi.RPCApi$ServerToClient$Companion.fromClientMessage(RPCApi.kt:360) ~[corda-node-api-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:256) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.access$artemisMessageHandler(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:69) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$start$2.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:197) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$start$2.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:69) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandlerKt$sam$MessageHandler$6fb61eb3.onMessage(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt) ~[corda-rpc-3.2-corda.jar!/:?]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.callOnMessage(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1002) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl.access$400(ClientConsumerImpl.java:50) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientConsumerImpl$Runner.run(ClientConsumerImpl.java:1125) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:42) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.OrderedExecutor.doTask(OrderedExecutor.java:31) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.actors.ProcessorBase.executePendingTasks(ProcessorBase.java:66) ~[artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_172]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) [artemis-commons-2.6.2.jar!/:2.6.2]
```

Comment: To clarify, 1. What version of Corda was the CorDapp compiled against?; 2. What version of Corda does Spring Boot depend upon?

Comment: from gradle I am using
    ext.corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
    ext.corda_release_version = '3.2-corda'
    ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.1.0'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
    ext.quasar_version = '0.7.9'
    ext.junit_version = '4.12'

Comment: I’m good now. Basically I follow the instructions in https://docs.corda.r3.com/upgrade-notes.html?highlight=upgrading%20from%20corda%20open%20source 
I could not figure out local Maven repository but unzip corda-3.1-developer-pack.tar.gz and add them to my local cache under .m2/repository

Answer (score 0):

You need to switch the SpringBoot webserver's dependencies to Corda Enterprise as well. See https://docs.corda.r3.com/upgrade-notes.html#upgrading-from-corda-open-source.